# Как изменить размеры изображения в dearpygui?

Tags: python, dearpygui

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
 with dpg.texture_registry():
     width, height, _, data = dpg.load_image('image_path')
     dpg.add_static_texture(width=width, height=height, default_value=data)
     dpg.add_image(texture_tag=movie['id'])
```

Он корректно отрабатывает, но изображение вставляется по исходным размерам. Если же попробовать "наживую" указать размеры изображения -

```
with dpg.texture_registry():
         width, height, _, data = dpg.load_image('image_path')
         dpg.add_static_texture(width=100, height=200, default_value=data)
         dpg.add_image(texture_tag=movie['id'])
```

получится каша (прикрепляю скриншот)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять размеры изображения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы изображение корректно отображалось нужно чтобы сохранялись пропорции ширины и высоты с которыми была добавлена текстура(там должны быть оригинальные размеры),

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а изменять размеры можно уже при добавлении виджета:

```
with dpg.texture_registry(show=True):
    width, height, _, data = dpg.load_image('image_path')
    dpg.add_static_texture(width=width, height=height, default_value=data, tag="texture_tag")

with dpg.window(label="Tutorial"):
    width, height = dpg.get_item_width("texture_tag"), dpg.get_item_height("texture_tag")
    scale = .5
    dpg.add_image("texture_tag", width=width * scale, height=height * scale )
```

**Дополнение:**

В случае когда нужно использовать только часть изображения или сжать его под определенный размер без искажений (в виде линий) или даже зеркально отобразить, можно использовать `drawlist` и в нем уже отрисовать `draw_image` задав ему нужное положение, первый параметр указывает координаты левого верхнего угла где он будет отрисован, второй — координаты правого нижнего угла, третий и четвертый указывают в диапазоне от 0 до 1 координаты части изображения которую нужно отрисовать (`uv_min` — левый верхний угол, `uv_max` — правый нижний)

Вот пример отрисовывающий все изображение в заданных Вами размерах.

```
with dpg.window(label="Tutorial"):
    with dpg.drawlist(width=100, height=200):
        dpg.draw_image("texture_tag", (0, 0), (100, 200), uv_min=(0, 0), uv_max=(1, 1))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!

P.S. Как вы нашли такую же картинку, как у меня?)

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, вероятно тоже пригодится, изображение я взял из вашего вопроса, просто задал ему нужные размеры чтобы оно стало нормальным.